# Virtual dyanmic directory is getting appended to the original path just before the pages when cookiless="true"

Tags: cookies, session-state

When I am setting `cookieless = "true"` in webconfig, some dyanmic directory is getting added like this:

Original directory: `http://localhost:54410/MyTestProj/(S(tt3p2bzwszq3q355wmgcj445))/index.aspx`

Hence my fixed activation page is getting failed which I am sending to user:

```
http://localhost:54410/MyTestProj/Activate.aspx
```

How to get this dynamically added directory : (S(tt3p2bzwszq3q355wmgcj445))?